# When publishing a notebook on the web, can the download option be suppressed?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, publishing

In some cases, I'd like to be able to publish visualizations or interactive programs without providing access to the underlying code or proprietary embedded data. It's not clear to me whether preventing notebook download can be accomplished through notebook publishing on Wolfram Cloud.